# How do I safely tell if a client has closed a connection on their side

Tags: kotlin, sockets, ktor

I'm working on a socket server that handles data for a large, but limited number of clients. Occasionally, these clients will disconnect without my knowledge, most often clients waiting for data on a long polling request.

I've tried reading from these clients through `ByteReadChannel.read()`, but this will often silently fail without throwing an exception.

I do keep all connections in a set of `Connection`, how would I iterate through these and kill dead connections?

Comment: `ByteChannel.read()` will return -1 in this case. If that's what you mean by 'silently fail', there's your answer.